# What is the difference between this XML layout and corresponding Java layout?

Tags: android, layout

This following XML produces the large bold text that I'm looking for.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Review"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I would think this Java would do the same, but instead I get non-bold, default sized text. What gives?

```
    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    container.setBackgroundColor(Style.backgroundColor);    

    TextView header = new TextView(this);
    header.setText("Review");
    header.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    header.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    header.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    header.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    header.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);

    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 44, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    container.addView(header, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)px);
```

(And before you answer "Just use XML", I can't. This needs to be nicely packaged in a jar.)

Comment: Question: Couldn't you just zip the entire project? You know right click project>Export>highlight everything on your project>name it & location it goes to>then click finish. Taking out .xml doesn't mean you are losing out on a gigantic data of bytes.

Comment: FYI, since r14 of the tools, library projects which can include resources are packaged as JARs.

Comment: @sdfwer, The goal is to distribute an SDK for other developers. A single jar means that the integration pain is less.

Comment: @kabuko, I'll check it out... We also need the .jar to be backwards compatible to Android-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an alternative constructor:

```
TextView header = new TextView(this, null, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
```

And don't call `setTextAppearance` later. My guess is that `textAppearanceLarge` overrides the bold setting that you set right beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

well, using your custom implementation of the view is "almost" the same as using the XML code, however Android has some "bugs" when you try to inflate your custom view by doing it all in Java; I know this for sure since I've tried it before and using my layout in XML works fine and using my custom java layout just didnt load well...
So in other words, there is pretty much no difference but you will have to write down a bit more of code and your app is susceptible to little bugs like this.
here is the link of the thread where I asked this time ago:
[Android Developers Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9a8b87d986ee6207/210905ddbfc8d1fc)

**Note**: you can just pack your proyect to a jar file but Android apps use APKs to be installed. I'm not sure if you can install jar app files, but I don't think its possible.